# Qualify and Rank : Filtering data on text and timestamp in Teradata

Tags: filter, teradata, rank

I have a dataset in Teradata-

ID  NAME    TMS
123 AAA 12:00
123 BBB 12:01
123 CCC 12:04
123 BBB 12:06
123 DDD 12:08
123 EEE 12:55
222 AAA 12:33
222 BBB 12:10

The query should first find out last "BBB" in Name column for a unique ID, and then display every row after that which is within 30 minutes interval of BBB timestamp. Hence, my display shoudl look like-

ID  NAME    TMS
123 BBB 12:06
123 DDD 12:08
222 BBB 12:10
I am guessing that Qualify and Rank can do the trick, but not sure. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `RANK`:

```
SELECT * FROM tab
QUALIFY TMS BETWEEN MAX(CASE WHEN NAME = 'BBB' THEN TMS end) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) 
                AND MAX(CASE WHEN NAME = 'BBB' THEN TMS end) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
```

Comment: Nice! Never would have considered that combination.

Comment: But, I have one more question- What would the qualify statement look like if I want to find the ID which has only BBB as name? For example if ID 111 has rows listed with name AAA in row 1, BBB in row 2, CCC in row 3, then I dont need ID 111. If ID 223 has only one row with BBB as name, I want to display ID 223. Now here there might be duplicates for ID 223 with BBB in row1, BBB in row2. I still want one single row (the first one) as the output. If any ID is listed with more than one name, I dont want it. How do I do this?

Comment: @ASuit: This will find rows where there's only a single Name: `QUALIFY MIN(NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) = MAX(NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TMS) = 1`